Irreducibility of $t^n+t^4+t^2+1$
I am trying to give necessary and sufficient conditions on $n$ for the polynomial $p(t)=t^n+t^4+t^2+1$ to be irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[t]$. I believe $p(t)$ to be reducible iff $n\equiv_42$. In the reverse direction, I have shown that
$$t^{4m+2}+t^4+t^2+1=(t^2+1)(1+\sum_{k=0}^{2m-2}(-1)^kt^{2k+4})$$
So, it remains to show $p(t)$ is irreducible when $n\not\equiv_42$. Since $p(t)$ is primitive, Gauss's Lemma tells us that it is sufficient to show irreducibility in $\mathbb{Z}[t]$. My thought was to show $p(t)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p$ for some $p$, but I'm not sure how to go about this. Any advice would be appreciated!

Fortunately we stand on the shoulders of giants…! Ljunggren* proved that polynomials of this form are always irreducible unless they have roots of unity as roots. And it's not hard to check (just by considering the modulus of $t^4+t^2+1$ when $t$ is a primitive root of unity) that these polynomials can only have roots of unity of order $4$ or $8$, both of which are confined to the case when $n\equiv 2\pmod 4$. So your conjecture is both correct and within the bounds of known mathematics.
*reference: W. Ljunggren, ‘On the irreducibility of certain trinomials and quadrinomials’, Math. Scand. 8 (1960) 65–70. Edited to add: a learned colleague told me that the general statement in Ljunggren's paper is not quite correct, although the mistake doesn't affect what I've said in this answer. A corrected version of Ljunggren's result can be found in this 1985 paper of Mills.

I wasted the past two hours agonising over this, haha. I can't access the article because I don't use university libraries anymore. If you plot the roots for different examples of $n\neq 4k+2$, you will see that all but one of the roots are inside the unit circle. I've tried finding a trick whereby Rouché's can then be directly applied, but I haven't found it.

If you send me an email I can send you the paper.

@ChrisSanders It's free here: https://www.mscand.dk/article/view/10593/8614

@ChrisSanders I don't think that observation is correct; e.g. for $n=11$  I count 5 roots outside of the unit circle.
